# T-SQL How to get SUM() from a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need fast answer (I can't check that code right now):

is that query works ? I need to get the total sum of a column values from the subquery, something like that:

```
  select sum(select time from table) as sometimes group by sometimes
```

Comment: 1. You can't slap that in Query Analyzer and check for yourself? 2. You're doing a SUM on a *time*? It depends on the datatype. 3. I don't think it will work as you're grouping by a table alias?

Comment: the "time" column is an INT column data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesnot work,
try this

```
select sum(time) as sumtime from table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(field_val)
from table1
where field_val in (
  SELECT TOP 3 field_val
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY field_val DESC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a subquery.  You only have 1 from...

Comment: And what @Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; -- said.